# Character encoding issues when transforming DOM Document to ByteArrayOutputStream in Java

Tags: java, dom, character-encoding

I am getting special characters as a result of transformation from DOM Document to ByteArrayOutputStream. The Document object is fine in terms of content,I mean, tags' content with Latin characters (i.e "ç", "ú", "Ú", "ã", etc) are right. However, the transformation to ByteArrayOutputStream results with weird characteres. For instance, the Latin character "Ú" is presented as "Ãš" (two bytes). Clearly, this is a problem related with encoding conversion, but I don't expected to get this at this point.
The conversion from DOM Document to ByteArrayOutputStream is performed by the following method:

```
private String write(final Document doc) throws TransformerException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();

    trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");        
    trans.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(os)); //Here is the problem

    String xmlData = os.toString(); //The conversion error is passed on

    return xmlData;
}
```

I bit more detail regarding this issue. This very same method works fine when the application is running on Linux/UNIX. When the application runs on Windows OS family the transformation doesn't work at all. Yet, while I was debugging this method, I noticed that the content of "os" object has already its content with the wrong representation of the character "Ú", which leads me that the problem occurs during the trans.transform execution.

Can some one help me to fix this problem, please? What should I do in order to avoid this encoding issue?

Thank you in advance for the help.
Regards,
Anderson

**UPDATE:**
Hi Makaveli84! Here is the outcome. Based on your suggestion I have made the change in the code, making sure that the encoding is "ISO-8859-1". This fixed the special characters problem; however, the XML declaration was changed from

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

That's make sense, but the business case restricts the XML declaration to

Having said that, what I decide to do was to get rid of the XML declaration by setting doing this

```
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes")
```

Afterwards, I just added the string `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` via concatenation, as follows:

```
xmlData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>".concat(os.toString());
```

This was the method I've found the keep the Latin characters in the XML during the conversion to String, I mean, this is a workaround in my humble opinion.

Clearly, this is not an elegant way to tackle the original problem posted here. Then my question is: Is there some way to achieve my goal by not using the above solution?

Here is the complete method after the adjustments made:

```
private String write(final Document doc) throws TransformerException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();

    trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
    trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");
    trans.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(os));

    String xmlData = null;

    xmlData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>".concat(os.toString());

    return xmlData;
}
```

**Findings on smoke test:**
I tested the new approach on Windows and now the problem was fixed. On the other hand, on Linux the code produces special characters, I mean, on Linux Latin character turned to be misrepresented (i.e. 'Ó' became '¿' in XML).

Should I test which operating system is running the application in order to handle Latin characters properly?

Any suggestion is welcome...

Comment: I think your identification of the problem is wrong. Try using `os.toString("UTF-8")` instead of `os.toString()`

Comment: Thank you Alohci! In the previous post I mentioned that I have changed the code by adding "UTF-8" to 'os.toString' according to your recommendation. Iam gonna run the application in order to validate the solution. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Half of your problem can be solved by decoding (transforming) into a byte array using a single-byte mapping charset such as `ISO-8859-1`.

Change this

`trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");`

to this

`trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");`

However, there is no escape when going from byte-array to `String`. You need to have detected the original encoding and use that information when converting the byte-array `toString`. For example:

`String xmlData = os.toString("UTF-8");`

or

`String xmlData = os.toString("UTF-16");`

Comment: Hi Makaveli84! First of all, thank you for support. I have done the proposed change in the code. So far the encoding issue was fixed. Using 'trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-8859-1");'  makes the content of 'os' object to be right, meaning that now the Latin character "Ú" is stored as "Ú", rather than "Ãš". I'm gonna make a smoking test on Linux and Windows ir order to discard any side effects due to the change made in the code.